# Targeting specific button class on javascript

Tags: javascript, css, mouseevent, addeventlistener, event-listener

I'm trying to add an Event Listener to the three buttons, so it highlights the specific area of the map that has the same color with the button.

However, I'm not really sure which class I'm supposed to target...
The HTML file code I have is here:

```
<div class="u-layout">
        <div class="u-layout-row">
          <div
            class="u-container-style u-layout-cell u-left-cell u-size-25 u-layout-cell-1"
          >
            <div class="u-container-layout u-container-layout-1">
              <h2 class="u-custom-font u-text u-text-1">
                おすすめ留学エリア
              </h2>
              <div
                class="u-border-5 u-border-palette-2-base u-line u-line-horizontal u-line-1"
              ></div>
              <p class="u-text u-text-2">
                世界2位の面積を誇るカナダは移民や留学生を迎え入れる体制が整っているため、日本人留学生にも人気の渡航先です。<br />自然が多く、治安もいい環境で安心して生活が可能で、語学留学、ワーキングホリデー、中学・高校留学、専門留学など様々な分野で注目を受けています。<br />公用語が英語とフランス語のため、英語以外にフランス語を学べる地域もあります。<br />どこに行けばいいか分からない方ならぜひこちらへ。
              </p>
              <a
                href="High-School-Exchange-.html#carousel_e4e6"
                data-page-id="63746825"
                class="u-border-none u-btn u-button-style u-custom-color-10 u-hover-custom-color-2 u-hover-feature u-text-white u-btn-1"
                >バンクーバーエリア</a
              >
              <a
                href="High-School-Exchange-.html#carousel_cbe7"
                data-page-id="63746825"
                class="u-border-none u-btn u-button-style u-custom-color-11 u-hover-feature u-hover-palette-2-base u-btn-2"
                >BC州内地エリア</a
              >
              <a
                href="High-School-Exchange-.html#carousel_cc0e"
                data-page-id="63746825"
                class="u-border-none u-btn u-button-style u-custom-color-9 u-hover-custom-color-4 u-hover-feature u-btn-3"
                >南BC州エリア</a
              >
            </div>
          </div>
```

I originally thought it would be the `u-border-none u-btn u-button-style u-custom-color-10 u-hover-custom-color-2 u-hover-feature u-text-white u-btn-1` but when I tested in the JS file as:

```
const green_btn = document.querySelector(".u-border-none u-btn u-button-style u-custom-color-10 u-hover-custom-color-2 u-hover-feature u-text-white u-btn-1")

const pink_btn = document.querySelector(".u-border-none u-btn u-button-style u-custom-color-11 u-hover-feature u-hover-palette-2-base u-btn-2")

const blue_btn = document.querySelector(".u-border-none u-btn u-button-style u-custom-color-11 u-hover-feature u-hover-palette-2-base u-btn-2")

green_btn.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
    console.log(e)
})
```

It wouldn't respond to the class reference. So I'm wondering which class do I target for this Event Listener to occur?

Currently, the button zooms in with different color when the mouse hovers over it.
[In browser view of the button attributes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyU57.jpg)
[Hover button effect as of right now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7KgY.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

place a dot before every css class and remove spaces

```
const green_btn = document.querySelector(".u-border-none.u-btn.u-button-style.u-custom-color-10.u-hover-custom-color-2.u-hover-feature.u-text-white.u-btn-1")

const pink_btn = document.querySelector(".u-border-none.u-btn.u-button-style.u-custom-color-11.u-hover-feature.u-hover-palette-2-base.u-btn-2")

const blue_btn = document.querySelector(".u-border-none.u-btn.u-button-style.u-custom-color-11.u-hover-feature.u-hover-palette-2-base.u-btn-2")

green_btn.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
  console.log(e)
})
```